# How can I use DESCRIBE and DUMP inside nested FOREACH

Tags: hadoop, foreach, apache-pig

I'm new in Pig and I some times I need to access schema for relations inside nested `FOREACH`. For example:

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (url:chararray,outlink:chararray);

DUMP A;
(www.ccc.com,www.hjk.com)
(www.ddd.com,www.xyz.org)
(www.aaa.com,www.cvn.org)
(www.www.com,www.kpt.net)
(www.www.com,www.xyz.org)
(www.ddd.com,www.xyz.org)

B = GROUP A BY url;

DUMP B;
(www.aaa.com,{(www.aaa.com,www.cvn.org)})
(www.ccc.com,{(www.ccc.com,www.hjk.com)})
(www.ddd.com,{(www.ddd.com,www.xyz.org),(www.ddd.com,www.xyz.org)})
(www.www.com,{(www.www.com,www.kpt.net),(www.www.com,www.xyz.org)})

X = FOREACH B {
        FA = FILTER A BY outlink == 'www.xyz.org';
        PA = FA.outlink;
        DA = DISTINCT PA;
        GENERATE group, COUNT(DA);
}

DUMP X;
(www.aaa.com,0)
(www.ccc.com,0)
(www.ddd.com,1)
(www.www.com,1)
```

I want to know what is the structure of FA, PA and DA. I have tried to use `DESCRIBE` inside `FOREACH` block but it gives error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 13, column 13>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'FA'
```

Is there any way to get schema and structure of relations inside nested `FOREACH` just for learning purpose?

Comment: You can project FA in the GENERATE statement and then dump and describe X. Then go with PA and then with DA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have multiple runs and project FA/PA/DA in GENERATE statements. Sample code with projecting FA:

```
X = FOREACH B {
    FA = FILTER A BY outlink == 'www.xyz.org';
    --PA = FA.outlink;
    --DA = DISTINCT PA;
    GENERATE group, FA;
}

DUMP X;
DESCRIBE X;
```